# How to return percentiles for different variables in one calculation in R?

Tags: r, percentile

I have a dataset along the lines of that below (but many more entries) and am trying to see if there is a way in R to calculate the percentile rank in a new column ("Column D") that would be a percentile ranking for user in each project by number of contributions. For example, user 2 has contributed to 3 projects, but much more to Project2 than 3 or 4. I would like to see the different percentile ranks in each of these projects for this user in a new Column. I hope that makes sense.

| User | ProjectName | Contributions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | Project1 | 1 |
| user2 | Project1 | 1 |
| user2 | Project2 | 2937533 |
| user2 | Project3 | 15 |
| user3 | Project4 | 8 |
| user4 | Project3 | 2 |
| user5 | Project6 | 277 |
| user5 | Project2 | 2 |

etc...

I tried several variations using group_by %>% summarize with no luck so far, and do not have much experience with creating my own functions, so was hoping there might already be a way of doing this that I am overlooking.

Comment: `df %>% group_by(User) %>% mutate(prank = percent_rank(Contributions))`?

Comment: @Axeman Thanks so much! I had to make one small tweak and group by project rather than user, but I think this is what I needed. Appreciate it.